# send authorization header negotiate with http request in angular

Tags: angular, http

First I'm new in this type of authorization, so I would like to ask somethings about it
I would like to send authorization header Negotiate with http request in angularjs.
I know that the Basic authentication can be sent as the following

```
headers.set("Authorization", "Basic Base64("user:pass")")
```

but what about Negotiate?
How the username and password are encoded? and how they are sent? also how to determine whether it is Kerberos or NTLM

Answer (score 0):

Username/Password can be sent to a server over request body, definitely not damn secured but that is the global standard for CRUD Operations.

If you are dealing with some CSRF/JWT token system, you are supposed to use HTTP interceptors in angularjs, once the user successfully logs in to the app, the server will send a token to the client with success message. You must store this token in `localStorage` of the browser.

Then you angular `http inteceptors` will be picking the token from storage add to each call being made to the server.

Sample interceptor code is below:

```
module.factory('sessionInjector', ['SessionService', function(SessionService) {  
var sessionInjector = {
    request: function(config) {
        if (!SessionService.isAnonymus) {
            config.headers['x-session-token'] = SessionService.token;
        }
        return config;
    }
};
return sessionInjector;
 }]);

module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjector');
 }]);
```

More it is been explained in this [blog](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)